# Reloading modules in IPython does not work

Tags: ipython, jupyter

I have a `.ipython_kernel_config.py` set as follows:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']   
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload']

# Run these commands on startup
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
                                    # imports
                                    "import pandas as pd",
                                    "import numpy as np",
                                    "from scipy import stats",
                                    "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt",
                                    "import statsmodels.api as sm",
                                    "import os",

                                    # Set options
                                    "pd.set_option('display.width', 200)",
                                    "pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 200)",

                                    # Change working directory and import from everything.py
                                    "os.chdir('/home/farasi/py_modules')",
                                    "from everything import *",

                                    # Set variables
                                    "data = '/home/farasi/data/entries.xlsx'",
                                    "results = '/home/farasi/data/results.xlsx'"
                                    ]
```

Everything seem to run fine as set in the `.ipython_kernel_config.py` file except for the autoreloading which does not work. What am I doing wrong? I'm using `Jupyter` on Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit.

Comment: This might help: https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469240-Jupyter-IPython-After-editing-a-module-changes-are-not-effective-without-kernel-restart

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the doc: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html

> %autoreload
>
> Reload all modules (except those excluded by %aimport) automatically **now**.

You should use `%autoreload 2` which will reload the code when needed.